# Plentymarkets Shopsystem - redirects

Tags: redirect, e-commerce

I'm looking to add some redirects to a plentymarkets-sytsem.
I do not see any place for that (just mobile and general rewrite for 404).

Where I am able to add custom redirects (like a .htaccess file)?
I heard that is possible to add up to 150 redirects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I looked at the website for this system, and it seems to like it's an e-commerce platform that doesn't have anything to do with programming. This is a GUI navigation question, in any case.

Comment: i dont understand? its a cloud based shop system!

Answer (score 0):

ok again: its a cloud based shop-system. I managed to get the redirects to work. Since its cloud based, plenty got the redirects in their hands. There is a Tab in the "service center" (reachable via the "Plenty-account"-tab in backend) called "system". there you are able to add your redrects: they costs 0,01 € per redirect!!! ...very strange shop-system.